# What to name 2 methods with same signatures

Tags: c#

Initially I had a method in our DL that would take in the object it's updating like so:

```
internal void UpdateCash(Cash Cash)
{
    using (OurCustomDbConnection conn = CreateConnection("UpdateCash"))
    {
        conn.CommandText = @"update Cash
                             set    captureID = @captureID,
                                    ac_code = @acCode,
                                    captureDate = @captureDate,
                                    errmsg = @errorMessage,
                                    isDebit = @isDebit,
                                    SourceInfoID = @sourceInfoID,
                                    PayPalTransactionInfoID = @payPalTransactionInfoID,
                                    CreditCardTransactionInfoID = @CreditCardTransactionInfoID
                                 where id = @cashID";

        conn.AddParam("@captureID", cash.CaptureID);
        conn.AddParam("@acCode", cash.ActionCode);
        conn.AddParam("@captureDate", cash.CaptureDate);
        conn.AddParam("@errorMessage", cash.ErrorMessage);
        conn.AddParam("@isDebit", cyberCash.IsDebit);
        conn.AddParam("@PayPalTransactionInfoID", cash.PayPalTransactionInfoID);
        conn.AddParam("@CreditCardTransactionInfoID", cash.CreditCardTransactionInfoID);
        conn.AddParam("@sourceInfoID", cash.SourceInfoID);
        conn.AddParam("@cashID", cash.Id);

        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

My boss felt that creating an object every time just to update one or two fields is overkill.  But I had a couple places in code using this.  He recommended using just UpdateCash and sending in the ID for CAsh and field I want to update.  Well the problem is I have 2 places in code using my original method.  And those 2 places are updating 2 completely different fields in the Cash table.  Before I was just able to get the existing Cash record and shove it into a Cash object, then update the properties I wanted to be updated in the DB, then send back the cash object to my method above.

I need some advice on what to do here.  I have 2 methods and they have the same signature.  I'm not quite sure what to rename these because both are updating 2 completely different fields in the Cash table:

```
internal void UpdateCash(int cashID, int paypalCaptureID)
{
    using (OurCustomDbConnection conn = CreateConnection("UpdateCash"))
    {
        conn.CommandText = @"update Cash
                             set    CaptureID = @paypalCaptureID
                  where id = @cashID";

        conn.AddParam("@captureID", paypalCaptureID);

        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

internal void UpdateCash(int cashID, int PayPalTransactionInfoID)
{
    using (OurCustomDbConnection conn = CreateConnection("UpdateCash"))
    {
        conn.CommandText = @"update Cash
                             set    PaymentSourceID = @PayPalTransactionInfoID
                  where id = @cashID";

        conn.AddParam("@PayPalTransactionInfoID", PayPalTransactionInfoID);

        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

So I thought hmm, maybe change the names to these so that they are now unique and somewhat explain what field its updating:

```
UpdateCashOrderID

UpdateCashTransactionInfoID
```

ok but that's not really very good names.  And I can't go too generic, for example:

```
UpdateCashTransaction(int cashID, paypalTransactionID)
```

What if we have different types of transactionIDs that the cash record holds besides just the paypalTransactionInfoID?  such as the creditCardInfoID?  Then what?  Transaction doesn't tell me what kind.  And furthermore what if you're updating 2 fields so you have 2 params next to the cashID param:

```
UpdateCashTransaction(int cashID, paypalTransactionID, someOtherFieldIWantToUpdate)
```

see my frustration?  what's the best way to handle this is my boss doesn't like my first route?

Comment: Btw you should not start paramters with an upper case letter (PayPalTransactionInfoID should be payPalTransactionInfoID)

Comment: Sorry all I need to update this post.  There was a problem with the site.

Comment: Is it actually causing problems?  There's a good chance your boss just needs a nice hot cup of STFU...

Comment: lol, I know.  It makes my life difficult, that's for damn sure when trying to code and I have to redo every method his way outside of just general team patterns

Comment: This code is running a high load e-commerce site so yea, an extra object here and there DOES make a difference so I can't argue with that...but it just complicates our code when I can't use the first update method.

Comment: Yo Oskar, that was a typo mistake in this thread...I don't start my params in upper case.  I modified it for this thread and accidentally mistyped it.  Obiviously my other params are all starting with lower-case ay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My boss felt that creating an object every time just to update one or two fields is overkill.

He would be right, *if* you have to create the object every time.  The correct response to this is that you should already be using these business objects throughout your app.  You don't create a new Cash object.  You pass it the Cash object you already have to be saved.

Comment: yea he makes a lot of made-up reasons why he wants everything done his way right down to the point where I can't even freakin code anymore...hey might as well take over my damn keyboard...when half the time he's not even right..which is why I like to verify with other smart developers here...thanks.

Comment: He still thinks foreach loops are faster than for loops.

Comment: @coffeeaddict - you _should_ prefer foreach vs for when you can. The performance difference is miniscule and more than justified by semantic improvements.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
UpdateCashPaymentSource(int cashID, int PayPalTransactionInfoID)

UpdateCashCapture(int cashID, int paypalCaptureID)
```

Comment: Yes, not bad but what does CApture really mean to the caller?  They would not infer that it's actually updating the field CaptureID.  And lets say hypothetically you had a bunch of CaptureThis CaptureThat fields in this cash table.  Then Capture becomes too generic and the caller really does have to now go into the method to see the code.  But the entire point in naming methods is so that you are explaining better what the method does to the caller so they don't have to always step into the method just to understand what lets say for example Capture means in this scenario

Comment: Seems like you're trying to put all your comments into the name. Append an "ID" to the Capture then. But a caller should not go only by the name of the method but mostly on the xml-documentation of the method! Append "///" above your method signature and fill out the xml. Then it will always be clear to a caller what the parameters are and what the method does.

Comment: Yes, but what if you have lazy developers who are good coders and don't document much....yes it's a team issue but it happens and so then you are reliant on that method name.  That's why it's good practice to know the right way to name your methods, classes, really any object, property, or method so that the consumer doesn't have to sit there and dig EVERY time in that code to figure out what the intent is.  Sure sometimes you do have to but the goal is to name things cleanly (Uncle Bob) and I agree with that 100%.  Sometimes it's a tough decision based on several factors (lenth of name, etc.)

Comment: Well yeah but it's the same person setting the name of the method as it is documenting it(you in this case) so you can document whatever you want! ;)

Comment: Remove some of the pain of writing XML comments using GhostDoc- http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

"UpdateCashWithCapture" and "UpdateCashWithTransaction"?

Answer (score 1):

UpdateCashByTransactionInfoID
UpdateCashByCaptureID()

?

Comment: Nice, but what if you are updating by 2 parameters now or 3 or 4.  Do you see why the name if it's dependent on the ID becomes a brick wall once the Update is based on multiple fields not a singluar ID!  I get a headache sometimes thinking the best route to go on this which is why I posted my thread here in stackoverflow.  I don't really have any other developers to ping this off of...we have no team here.

Answer (score 1):

Would one method and an enum cut it?

```
internal void UpdateCash(int cashID, int id, FieldName field)
{
    using (OurCustomDbConnection conn = CreateConnection("UpdateCash"))
    {
        conn.CommandText = string.format("update Cash set {0} = @id where id = @cashID", field.ToString());

        conn.AddParam("@id", id);
        conn.AddParam("@cashId", cashId);

        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

public enum FieldName
{
    PayPalCaptureId,
    PayPalTransactionInfoID
}
```

**EDIT:**

On now reading your edit, I would agree that your original approach would be the way to go, in my opinion - passing in an object and updating all of the associated fields in a database compared to passing in an object property value and updating that in a database, the biggest performance killer will be opening the database connection, not the number of fields relating to one database record.

Comment: @Jeffrey - it was an alternative angle on the question before it was edited :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `UpdateCashByCaptureID` and `UpdateCashByTransactionInfoID`?

Comment: The "by" part is the same on both of them. It's the updates part that differs

Comment: Yes, and then domain driven DL experts will hate this.  BUt yea, this to me is the way I always like to do it.  But now what if that method name gets super long because the fieldnames are long?  Then it becomes unreadable.  Furthermore, what if you now want to create an update method that is going to up 2 fields, or 3 fields...so now you are taking in more params.  Then what?  What do you name it so it's inferring what it does without having to look in its internals all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Add the name of the field being updated, i.e.

```
internal void UpdateCash_paypalCaptureID(...)
internal void UpdateCash_PayPalTransactionInfoID(...)
```

Comment: I don't use underscores in method names...bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate the update query logic in a class:

```
public abstract class CashUpdateQuery
{
    public CashUpdateQuery(int cashId)
    {
        this.CashId = cashId;
    }

    protected int CashId { get; private set; }

    public abstract void SetConnectionProperties(OurCustomDbConnection conn);
}
```

Then you can have specific subclasses for each update scenario. So for your PayPal query you'd have something like this:

```
public PaypalTransactionCashUpdateQuery : CashUpdateQuery
{
    private readonly int paypalCaptureId;
    public PaypalTransationCashUpdateQuery(int cashId, int paypalCaptureId)
    {
        this.paypalCaptureId = paypalCaptureId;
    }

    public override void SetConnectionProperties(OurCustomDbConnection conn)
    {
        conn.CommandText = @"update Cash
                            set    CaptureID = @paypalCaptureID
                            where id = @cashID";

        conn.AddParam("@captureID", this.paypalCaptureId);
        conn.AddParam("@cashID", this.CashId);
    }
}
```

Then your update method can take a query object and use it to set the query properties on the connection and execute it:

```
internal void UpdateCash(CashUpdateQuery query)
{
    using(OurCustomDbConnection conn = CreateConnection("UpdateCash"))
    {
        query.SetConnectionProperties(conn);
        conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This means that adding new queries is simply a case of adding a new subclass of CashUpdateQuery.

Comment: well unfortunately I have a boss right now that would deem this as "overkill"